# multiple select field - select field must be an array and just one <option> is shown in the $request output

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below that is a resume of the process to create a new conference. To create a new conference is ncessary that the user introduce some info like the conference name, etc. The user also needs to introduce between 1 and 3 categories for the conference.

So there is a select element using select2 plugin so the user can select the categories:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="categories">Category</label>
        <select id="tag_list" required  multiple class="form-control" value="{{ old('categories') }}" name="categories" id="categories">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the laravel code to store the conference info and also the categories of the conference in the conference_category table since there is a many to many relationship between confernece and category:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'conference_categories' => 'required|array|between:1,3|integer',
        ]);

        $conference = Conference::create([
            'name' => $request->conference_name,
        ]);

        $conference->categories()->attach($request->conference_categories);
    }
```

The select2 JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tag_list').select2({
        placeholder: '',
        dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
        width: '100%'
    });
});
```

**Errors**

- If the user selects more than one category in the $request output just appears the id of one category
- And it appears a laravel validation error after submit the form "The conference categories must be an array.
  "

Do you know where can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta change the `name` attribute of your `select` to an array, like this and also remove one `id` attribute from it, it can't have 2

```
<select required  multiple class="form-control" value="{{ old('categories') }}" name="categories[]" id="categories">
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it appears other error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given." Do you know why?

Comment: try removing `value` attribute from `select`

Comment: Removing that appears a laravel validation error "The conference categories must be an integer."

Comment: `'categories' => 'required|array'` instead of `conference_categories`

Comment: Thanks, but i get the same issue. If I change to "value="{{ old('conference_categories') }}"" "value="{!! old('conference_categories') !!}"" appears:  Array to string conversion error.

Comment: remove the `value` attribute from `select`, then change the validation inside of your controller instead of `conference_categories` to be `'categories' => 'required|array'`